# Password for full disk encryption not accepted on boot

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, encryption, boot-loader

I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. My Ubuntu partition is encrypted, and I have a separate boot partition.

A Windows update wiped out GRUB, so I used boot-repair to reinstall it. I got a dialogue about decrypting a volume, but couldn't work out what it wanted me to do. Otherwise, it seemed to work OK.

The GRUB menu now appears, but when I try to decrypt it won't accept my password. However, if I boot with a live USB, I can decrypt the volume with `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda6 encrypted` and the same password!

I've run out of ideas of what to try next. My guess would be either to run boot-repair again and do *something* about the decryption error, but I'm not sure what.

Sorry about the vague descriptions of errors - I don't have access to the PC at the moment. If there's some information that might be helpful I can fetch it tomorrow.

Comment: Do your password contain non-ASCII characters?  In a live USB Xorg may perform a couple of conversions depending on the language setup (even if the language is `en_US.UTF-8`!  Since then it will translate keyboard keycodes into multibyte characters).  GRUB does not perform this at all, it takes what bytes are given to it.

Comment: @grochmal And even with only ASCII characters, you may have a similar problem with non-US keyboard layouts: the keyboard layout in the GUI is not necessarily the same as the keyboard layout early in the boot process. reogrape, what keyboard layout are you using? Try typing as if your keyboard had a [US QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#United_States) layout.

Comment: If it's due to keyboard layout, my answer is http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174657/30851

Comment: It's a fully alphanumeric password, so not keyboard layout I don't think. Thanks though.

Comment: I ran into the same issue :-/