# cryptsetup open for luks : improper handling of --key-file argument

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

A related question would be: [luksOpen doesn't decrypt with keyfile unless --key-file argument is provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369857/153088)

On Ubuntu bionic with `cryptsetup 2.0.2` however, I do encounter the following problem:

when opening a luks encrypted device by using a password contained in a file it **works well** on the direct call:

```
cat mypass.txt | sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sda1 enc-store
```

trying to use the documented `--key-file=-` argument, which **should result in the same behavior**

```
cat mypass.txt | sudo cryptsetup open --type luks --key-file=- /dev/sda1 enc-store
```

just producing the delayed message

> No key available with this passphrase.

this is especially a problem, when trying to use the script `cryptdisks_start enc-store`, which relies on the `--key-file=-` option, which produces the above message thrice

which makes life a tad less enjoyable.

am I missing something here?

-thanks!

Comment: Did you think about **not** including the final LF (`\n`) in the file?

Comment: I didn't expect vim to add a \n if there is no empty line at the end of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the two commands, as described in [`man cryptsetup`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cryptsetup-bin/cryptsetup.8.en.html#OPTIONS):

> --key-file, -d name
>     Read the passphrase from file.
>
> If  the name given is "-", then the passphrase will be read from stdin. **In this case, reading will not stop at  newline  characters.**

That means if you generated your file using `echo`, `vi`, or copy/pasting, it most likely includes a newline at the end. if used as pure stdin (no `--key-file` option), it will have its final newline ignored, but when used as a parameter to `--key-file`, even if it's the same stdin  (`--key-file=-` ) it will get this newline included in the passphrase: it becomes a new passphrase which is invalid.

To verify this:

```
cat mypass.txt | tr -d '\r\n' | sudo cryptsetup open --type luks --key-file=- /dev/sda1 enc-store
```

Should work as intended (just in case I remove any CR too).

Should that be the cause, just remove this newline: eg

```
mv -i mypass.txt mypass.old && tr -d '\r\n' < mypass.old > mypass.txt
```

What you should probably do anyway is to generate a new passphrase from pure random numbers, put it in a secure file, and include it in a separate LUKS slot.

Comment: and I thought, I had checked for that...
thanks :)